# Count without using functions (like count) oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

**TABLE A :**

```sql
CREATE TABLE z_ostan ( id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
                       name  VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL CHECK (upper(name)=name) 
                     );
```

**TABLE B:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE z_shahr ( id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
                       name  VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL CHECK (upper(name)=name),
                       ref_ostan NUMBER,
                       CONSTRAINT fk_ref_ostan FOREIGN KEY (ref_ostan) REFERENCES z_ostan(id)
                    );
```

**How can I find the second and third place "id" from -Table A- The least used table B in the table?    Without using predefined functions like "count()"**

Comment: Why "without using `count()`? That is the most natural and fastest way to solve the problem. A lot faster still if you have an index on `ref_ostan` - if I understand your problem correctly: find the three id's from table A that appear the *fewest* times as `ref_ostan` in table B. Is that right? (And if an id from A does not appear at all in B, does that count as "appears 0 times", so that is the fewest times?)

Comment: Without using predefined functions like "count()" - does it mean "without any aggregate or analytic functions"? Should you do it in pure SQL or in any language? In the latter case write a PL/SQL procedure and count rows yourself. If it is some kind of exercise, perhaps it's worth checking what context it appears in - what features are discussed, etc.

Comment: 1) solve the problem *using COUNT* (it is not realy clear what is the target). 2) rewrite it *without COUNT*, e.g. `SUM` can easy *simulate* COUNT. If even this is *not aloved* write your own code...

Comment: What behavior did you want in the case of matching counts?  Do you want to handle it like DENSE_RANK, where we might see more than one 2nd and/or 3rd least used count, or do you want to break the ties arbitrarily with the primary key?  Best to show actual cases with your expected results for each of the various cases.

Comment: @mathguy This Is practice and Because Of This I cant Use count. But The Question: We have FK IN TABLE B Comes From Table A. We Want To Count How Many times Id From Table A Used In Table B and Print 2nd and 3rd That minimum repeats in Table B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only processes existing references to Table A.

Updated for oracle (used 12c)

Without using any aggregate or window functions:

Sample data for Table: tblb

```
+----+---------+---------+
| id | name    | tbla_id |
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 | TBLB_01 |       1 |
|  2 | TBLB_02 |       1 |
|  3 | TBLB_03 |       1 |
|  4 | TBLB_04 |       1 | 4 rows
|  5 | TBLB_05 |       2 |
|  6 | TBLB_06 |       2 |
|  7 | TBLB_07 |       2 | 3 rows
|  8 | TBLB_08 |       3 |
|  9 | TBLB_09 |       3 |
| 10 | TBLB_10 |       3 |
| 11 | TBLB_11 |       3 |
| 12 | TBLB_12 |       3 |
| 13 | TBLB_13 |       3 | 6 rows
| 14 | TBLB_14 |       4 |
| 15 | TBLB_15 |       4 |
| 16 | TBLB_16 |       4 | 3 rows
| 17 | TBLB_17 |       5 | 1 row
| 18 | TBLB_18 |       6 |
| 19 | TBLB_19 |       6 | 2 rows
| 20 | TBLB_20 |       7 | 1 row
+----+---------+---------+
```

There are many ways to express this logic.

Step by step with CTE terms.
The intent is (for each set of tbla_id rows in tblb)

1. generate a row_number (n) for the rows in each partition.
   We would normally use window functions for this.
   But I assume these are not allowed.
2. Use this row_number (n) to determine the count of rows in each tbla_id partition.
   To find that count per partition, find the last row in each partition (from step 1).
3. Order the results of step 2 by n of these last rows.
   Choose the 2nd and 3rd row of this result
   Done.

```
WITH first AS (  -- Find the first row per tbla_id
          SELECT t1.*
            FROM      tblb t1
            LEFT JOIN tblb t2
              ON t1.id > t2.id
             AND t1.tbla_id = t2.tbla_id
           WHERE t2.id IS NULL
     )
   , rnum (id, name, tbla_id, n) AS (  -- Generate a row_number (n) for each tbla_id partition
          SELECT f.*, 1 FROM first f UNION ALL
          SELECT n.id, n.name, n.tbla_id, c.n+1
            FROM rnum  c
            JOIN tblb  n
              ON c.tbla_id = n.tbla_id
             AND c.id < n.id
            LEFT JOIN tblb n2
              ON n.tbla_id = n2.tbla_id
             AND c.id < n2.id
             AND n.id > n2.id
           WHERE n2.id IS NULL
     )
   , last AS (  -- Find the last row in each partition to obtain the count of tbla_id references
          SELECT t1.*
            FROM      rnum t1
            LEFT JOIN rnum t2
              ON t1.id < t2.id
             AND t1.tbla_id = t2.tbla_id
           WHERE t2.id IS NULL
     )
SELECT * FROM last
 ORDER BY n, tbla_id OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY
;
```

Final Result, where n is the count of references to tbla:

```
+------+---------+---------+------+
| id   | name    | tbla_id | n    |
+------+---------+---------+------+
|   20 | TBLB_20 |       7 |    1 |
|   19 | TBLB_19 |       6 |    2 |
+------+---------+---------+------+
```

Some intermediate results...

`last` CTE term result.  The 2nd and 3rd rows of this become the final result.

```
+------+---------+---------+------+
| id   | name    | tbla_id | n    |
+------+---------+---------+------+
|   17 | TBLB_17 |       5 |    1 |
|   20 | TBLB_20 |       7 |    1 |
|   19 | TBLB_19 |       6 |    2 |
|    7 | TBLB_07 |       2 |    3 |
|   16 | TBLB_16 |       4 |    3 |
|    4 | TBLB_04 |       1 |    4 |
|   13 | TBLB_13 |       3 |    6 |
+------+---------+---------+------+
```

`rnum` CTE term result.  This provides the row_number over tbla_id partitions ordered by id

```
+------+---------+---------+------+
| id   | name    | tbla_id | n    |
+------+---------+---------+------+
|    1 | TBLB_01 |       1 |    1 |
|    2 | TBLB_02 |       1 |    2 |
|    3 | TBLB_03 |       1 |    3 |
|    4 | TBLB_04 |       1 |    4 |
|    5 | TBLB_05 |       2 |    1 |
|    6 | TBLB_06 |       2 |    2 |
|    7 | TBLB_07 |       2 |    3 |
|    8 | TBLB_08 |       3 |    1 |
|    9 | TBLB_09 |       3 |    2 |
|   10 | TBLB_10 |       3 |    3 |
|   11 | TBLB_11 |       3 |    4 |
|   12 | TBLB_12 |       3 |    5 |
|   13 | TBLB_13 |       3 |    6 |
|   14 | TBLB_14 |       4 |    1 |
|   15 | TBLB_15 |       4 |    2 |
|   16 | TBLB_16 |       4 |    3 |
|   17 | TBLB_17 |       5 |    1 |
|   18 | TBLB_18 |       6 |    1 |
|   19 | TBLB_19 |       6 |    2 |
|   20 | TBLB_20 |       7 |    1 |
+------+---------+---------+------+
```

There are a few other ways to tackle this problem in just SQL.